# Changing select option displayed text after it is selected but return when changing the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show list of countries with select options like this:

```
<select id="country_code">
    <option value="358"> Finland(+358)</option>
    <option value="33"> France(+33)</option>
    <option value="43"> Austria(+43)</option>
</select>
```

When user selects a country, I want only the code to be displayed as the selected option.

This is what I've tried:

```
 $("#country_code").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").text("+"+$(this).find("option:selected").text().match(/(\d+)/g));

    })
```

This code is separating the Code (regex is for separating the number) from selected option and displays it instead of the full name, and it works.

But the problem is when I try to select some other countries, the previous options have changed! and i can not get it back.

it look like this :

```
<select id="country_code">
    <option value="358"> +358</option>
    <option value="33"> France(+33)</option>
    <option value="43"> +43</option>
</select>
```

How should I accomplish this? I have searched online with no results.

Comment: What you want is the once a country has been selected its code should be displayed but once another country is selected the previous conutry with full name and code should appear?

Comment: yes @Rahul , Can not get back previous fullname, because its changed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the previous selected data.
like this:

```js
 var $previousOption,storedText;
$("#country_code").change(function(){
    if($previousOption!=null){
       $previousOption.text(storedText)
    }   
      $previousOption=$(this).find("option:selected");
      storedText=$previousOption.text(); 

$(this).find("option:selected").text("+"+$(this).find("option:selected").text().match(/(\d+)/g));
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country_code">
    <option value="358"> Finland(+358)</option>
    <option value="33"> France(+33)</option>
    <option value="43"> Austria(+43)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: good answer. thanks.  1-because its optimum!  2- when I want to select another option, I can start from previous selection(don't have to start from first again) 3- does not need extra `data_text` for all options  4- does not need default selection with `display:none`

Answer (score 5):

My version: :)

```js
    $( "#country_code" ).change( function()
    {
        var $this = $( this )

        $this.find( "option:first" ).text( '+' + $this.val() ).val( $this.val() ).prop( 'selected', true )
    } )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country_code">
    <option value="" style="display: none;" selected="selected">select a country</option>
    <option value="358"> Finland(+358)</option>
    <option value="33"> France(+33)</option>
    <option value="43"> Austria(+43)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as the others (including the accepted) keep the "+prefix" format of the selected option in select list after changing and then redisplaying options.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `data` attributes to achieve what you want. You can add a `data-text` attribute with actual text and on `change` event you can first reset the options `text` to original.

```js
$("#country_code").change(function() {
  
  //reset options to there actual texts
  $(this).find("option").each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).data('text'));  
  });
  
  var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
  selectedOption.text("+" + selectedOption.text().match(/(\d+)/g));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country_code">
  <option value="358" data-text="Finland(+358)">Finland(+358)</option>
  <option value="33" data-text="France(+33)">France(+33)</option>
  <option value="43" data-text="Austria(+43)">Austria(+43)</option>
</select>
```

PART 2 : You don't even need to add any `regx` as the `option value` has what you need!

```js
$("#country_code").change(function() {
  
  //reset options to there actual texts
  $(this).find("option").each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).data('text'));  
  });
  
  var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
  selectedOption.text("+" + selectedOption.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country_code">
  <option value="358" data-text="Finland(+358)">Finland(+358)</option>
  <option value="33" data-text="France(+33)">France(+33)</option>
  <option value="43" data-text="Austria(+43)">Austria(+43)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was simple. I will use it.  is this way redundant? because there are 150 countries

Comment: I dont think so because anyway you are going to set text to your option so at same time you can add the data-text attribute as well. Please accept and upvote if found helpful.

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki also see another version of answer that i recommend you to use. Hope it also works for you. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I can gratitude you in other way's ;)

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki accepting and upvoting would be preferred one :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you wish to do this using Jquery or vanilla JS. But [Material UI](https://mui.com/) has an excellent component called [`<Select>`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/), which has a prop called [renderValue](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/), which does exactly this, with much less work. Check it out.